# jQuery on elements created via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Google Maps API and have a lot of html that is injected through the script using .html() etc. I have a few triggers set up to select those elements that are injected in, but as the HTML isn't 'ready' or 'loaded' it, it fails to select.

I thought a simple `$(window).load` would've worked, but it doesn't seem to be.

This is my code so far:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('ul.campaign-list li a').on('click', function (e) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
        alert("Scrolls");
    });
});
```

I am using .on, instead of .live() but I'm also guessing this would be the right way to do it. I added the alert(); in just to test my code but alas it still doesn't load.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
$('#container_12').on('click', 'a', function(){ 
  $('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: 300 
  }, 500); 
});
```

After the discussion in chat we pinpointed the problem and fixed it accordingly, i ll keep the original answer so it helps people with such a case.

When using `.on()` in order to get it to work for dynamic content you need to specify a container or context:

```
$('ul.campaign-list li a').on('click', function (e) {
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
   alert("Scrolls");
 });
```

Becomes :

```
$(window).on('click', 'ul.campaign-list li a', function (e) {
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
   alert("Scrolls");
});
```

Note that you can replace window with any container that isn't dynamically added.

Refer to the [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation for a more detailed description.

Comment: I thought this would work too, thanks, but it doesn't even do the alert so I'm assuming it's not working. There's no errors in my console.

Comment: @rdck Is it still wrapped in your `$(window).load()` function ? If so remove it and replace it with `$(function(){ your code goes here});`

Comment: @rdck What page are the `.campaign-list` at couldn't find them

Comment: Below the map – the list of venues

Comment: @rdck are you preventing default in your gotoPost() function ?

Comment: No, and even if I change it from the click from the a to the li, it still doesn't work. Weird.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38552/discussion-between-patsy-issa-and-rdck)

Answer (score 0):

1. jquery uses a different method to make sure the dom is ready, so instead of `$(window).load` use:

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
   });
   ```
2. When using on, the container you are binding to must be present when the page is loaded, so if you want to bind a click event to `a` which is dynamically added, you need to bind the `on` to the container which is not dynamic:

   ```
   $('ul.campaign-list li').on('click','a', function (e) {
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
       alert("Scrolls");
   });
   ```

Comment: `$( document ).ready()` checks if the dom is ready not loaded (pictures and such).

Comment: @PatsyIssa - just a miss-use of the word, obviously i meant 'ready' :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `$(window).load` for code that you want to run once the DOM has loaded, use `$(document).ready(function(){...})` or the shortcut `$(function(){...})` instead. Also, your `.on()` call will only apply to elements that exist at the time you make the call. I guess what you actually want is something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.campaign-list').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
    alert("Scrolls");
  });
});
```

This will trigger when anything matching the `li a` selector within the element(s) matched by `ul.campaign-list` is clicked - assuming the `ul` element is present in the page's HTML on loading.

The old `.live()` call is the equivalent of doing:

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul.campaign-list li a", function(ev) { ... });
```

if that helps